# OPENCV: Extract the lifetime for a frame in a video with variable frame rate

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, frame-rate

I'm using python OpenCV to read frames from a video file that has a **variable frame rate**.

I need to understand how the wall time changes between frames (i.e. I want to be able to write the timestamp on every frame). My understanding is that the underlying video format stores how long each frame *lasts* i.e. the video file contains the information to tell the video player how long it should display the given frame before moving to the next one.

I would like to programmatically access this data using the python OpenCV interface. An example (that does not work) of what this might look like is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture('my_variable_frame_rate_video.mp4')

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    frame_length_ms = ret.frame_length()   # obviously doesn't work

    print("The length of the frame in ms is {}".format(frame_length_ms))

   # Should print: The length of the frame in ms is 23
```

### Things that don't work

1. Reading the source frame rate from the capture device:

`fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)`

2. Counting the total number of frames:

`fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)/total_length`

Both of these don't work because we are dealing with a variable frame rate

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be extract the amount of time and write it in each frame

```
import cv2
import time

path="video.mp4"    
video = cv2.VideoCapture(path);

start = time.time()
ret, frame = video.read()
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
i = 0
while ret:
    start = time.time()
    ret, frame = video.read()
    end = time.time()
    seconds = end - start
    cv2.putText(frame,str(seconds),(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imwrite(str(i)+".jpg", frame)
    i+=1

video.release()
```

[image: Output first frame]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this code measures how long it took for the capture object to decode the frame - no how long the frame is supposed to last i.e. on a slower pc with a less powerful processor, decoding will take longer but the individual frame still represents a fixed amount of real-world time.